# Date add unexpected results

Tags: marketing-cloud, soql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM Account_Salesforce
WHERE (dateadd(year, (2020 - year(PersonBirthdate)), PersonBirthdate) >= dateadd(day, 7, GetDate()) AND dateadd(year, (2020 - year(PersonBirthdate)), PersonBirthdate) <= dateadd(day, 14, GetDate()))
```

This query should give me people who have their birthday on the 28th of February, until the 6th of March. However it is giving me from the 29th and onwards, I am missing the 28th.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with marketing cloud, but it might be a time zone problem? It's tomorrow in some places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem could be that when using GetDate(), it includes the time while the values stored for PersonBirthdate would not have time so the calculated date would be something like '2020-02-28 09:22:37.113' instead of '2020-02-28 00:00:00.000'

The date 7 days in the future without time can be obtained using something like:

```
select dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 7)
```